# How to nohup multiple SAS programs at once?

Tags: linux, shell-script, nohup, batch-jobs

I have several SAS programs

```
test1_2.sas
test3_4.sas
test7_8.sas
```

and I hope to `nohup` those scripts at once. I tried to create a shell wrapper such as a `test.sh`:

```
#test running multiple files
testing1_2.sas &
testing3_4.sas &
```

and I tried calling `nohup sas test.sh &` and `nohup test.sh &`. Both commands tell me `test.sh` is not in the current directory when it is clearly saved in the folder.

I am still quite new to shell scripting, and would like to have some help to find the right way for running `nohup` on multiple SAS programs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of nohup (I use disown instead), but if you put ‘nohup’ in front of each command in a shell script it will accomplish the nohup part of your question.

However, I think your files are SAS programs? If you want SAS run in parallel on each SAS program:

```
nohup sas test1_2.sas &
nohup sas test3_4.sas &
etc.
```

That will run independent SAS commands, each with it's own SAS program.

Continuing with the nohup command, if they produce output, they will all be writing to nohup.out at the same time. To prevent that, write output and error messages to a separate file for each command:

```
nohup sas test1_2.sas > output1_2.file 2>&1 &
nohup sas test3_4.sas > output3_4.file 2>&1 &
etc.
```

Added to include code from comments:

To invoke the test.sh command either

```
bash test.sh
```

(where “bash” is your favorite shell) or mark it as executable:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

Since you're new, make sure and click on the checkmark if you think this is the right answer to your question.

Comment: When I call test.sh do I still have to add nohup such as nohup test.sh &? Or should I do bash vi test.sh?

Comment: Personally I would put the nohup's in the script and invoke the script without nohup.

Comment: I anticipate another issue you may run into. When you invoke your test.sh shell script, you're either going to have to invoke it like this:

    bash test.sh

(where “bash” is your favorite shell) or mark the script as executable:

    chmod +x test.sh

Comment: Sorry, comments don't format the same as answers. I hope you understand what I typed. Let me know if you don't.

Comment: Thank you that’s helpful! I will let you know by tomorrow if this works. Have a good night!

Comment: You too! Make sure and accept the answer if it works the way you want.

Comment: one more question can I write the error to a .log instead of .file?

Comment: Oh, sure, that isn't a problem. Log is probably better.

Comment: I think the `> output1_2.file 2>&1` portion is giving me an error saying $'\r' command not found.. do I have to install anything ? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to remove the command and only kept nohup sas test1_2.sas ... in the shell script, and received this error : `nohup: failed to run command ‘testing1_2.sas’: No such file or directory` and `nohup: failed to run command ‘testing3_4.sas’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106293/discussion-between-larry-and-lydias).